# Prove If $ad - bc \neq 0$ then $f(z)$ not a constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

For the linear fractional transformation

$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, prove that $f(z)$ is not a constant if $ad-bc \neq 0$

I have tried proving this two different ways, which is the better proof?

**proof #1**

Assume $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus  
\{-\frac{d}{c}\}$.

Since holomorphic functions have determinant ad-bc = 1, then $f'(z) \neq 0$.

We have $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $f'(z) = \frac{a(cz+d)-c(az+b)}{(cz+d)^2} = \frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2} = \frac{1}{(cz+d)^2}$

Thus, $f(z)$ is not a constant.

**proof #2**

Suppose for some  $k \in \mathbb{C}$,

we have, $k(az+b) = cz + d$

Then for the equation coefficients,

$ka = cz$, $kb = d$, and $ad - bc = a(kb) - b(ka) = 0$

Hence, $ad-bc \neq 0$.

Thus $az+b$ and $cz+d$ have not common factor.

Therefore, $f(z)$ is well defined nonconstant holomorphic function.

Comment: Is that a typo toward the end, "Hence, $ad-bc\neq 0$."? What you had just showed is that $ad-bc=0$.  Perhaps you meant, "But we assume $ad-bc\neq 0$" or "Hence $ad-bc=0$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are fine.  Here's another:

$f(0)=f(1)\implies \frac{b}{d}=\frac{a+b}{c+d}\implies bc+bd=ad+bd\implies bc=ad$.

So if $f$ is constant, then in particular $f(0)=f(1)$ and the above shows that $ad-bc=0$.

That's valid unless $f(0)=f(1)=\infty$, but that would imply that $c=d=0$ which also implies $ad-bc=0$.

---

In (1), I would have two nitpicks about your wording: You don't "assume" $f$ is holomorphic, it just is.  You can use that it is holomorphic, or prove that it is holomorphic, but not assume it, which sounds almost like you're hypothesizing.

Then "we have $ab-bc=1$".  Why?  You could have $ad-bc=1$ if you want simply by rescaling the terms, but that has nothing to do with the function being holomorphic, and it isn't needed.  Without that you still get $f'(z)\neq 0$, which implies the function isn't constant.